# PHP File Uploads -- Original filename is being changed

Tags: php, file-upload

I have a tiny project going that acts as a bit of a file host for temporary storage of user files. Similar to UploadPie, if you know what that is. It's all been working fine, and I was just adding in some new features (namely, syntax highlighting upon viewing Javascript files) and suddenly things went all wonky with the uploads.

By "wonky", I mean the `$_FILES['upload']['name']` entry ("upload" is the file form element's name) is being changed upon uploading to some seemingly random, extensionless name beginning with "php". Which is annoying, since my script does its own renaming while retaining the original file extensions--and now it doesn't even GET the file extension.

The weirdest part is that it was working before, even during this testing round, and I have only been changing the viewing script, I haven't even TOUCHED the upload script. When I noticed the extensions weren't being retained, I did a bit of digging and that's how I found the filename issue. For example, when I upload a file called "css-tricks.js" and print_r the $_FILES superglobal, I get this output:

```
Array (
    [upload] => Array (
        [name] => php6pVzJG
        [type] => application/octet-stream
        [tmp_name] => C:\wamp\tmp\phpD7E6.tmp
        [error] => 0
        [size] => 1326
    )
)
```

Notice the filename was changed to "php6pVzJG"? That's never happened before. I tried restarting PHP and it continues doing this. I looked for a setting in php.ini and found nothing. Has anyone had this issue before?

If you need more info, I can post the code from the upload.php file, though as I said, I haven't changed that file at all since the last time it worked.

Comment: what is version of php you are using?

Comment: PHP 5.4.12, on a WAMP stack (Windows 8.1). For various reasons, I can't upgrade past that for now.

Comment: The *temporary* filename with which the upload payload gets stored is always arbitrary.

Comment: @mario Yes, I know. But that's in $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']. The problem is it's getting an arbitrary ACTUAL name, in $_FILES['upload']['name']. It's never done that before, and now I have no access to the original filenames.